# Selenium - element not being found (python)

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, webdriver, element

Tried using selenium to send keys to a textbox, but it can't seem to find the element even after using explicit waits.

Note: I just started learning python so I may be missing something big here.

Selenium has been able to find all elements on the site until this page (not sure if it is a new page because URL doesn't change, but modules within the page do). I have tried all the possible element locating methods(XPATH, ID, CLASS_NAME, etc.,) but it can't seem to find this textbox element. I tried using it to locate other elements on the page but it doesn't seem to be able to find them either.

```
#My code:
#imported expected_conditions as EC
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 15)
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '// 
[@id="payment_amount_value"]')))

#Element:
  <input type="text" class="input-mini text_input span10" 
   id="payment_amount_value" aria-describedby="payment-amount-error- 
   message" data-submit="paymentAmount">

    #Error Message:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 100, in <module>
      File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site- 
   packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 80, in until
        raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
    selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

Comment: Hi! You will get much better answers if you provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your help, Moshe! Turns out the element was in an iframe and I had to switch into it using:

```
iframe = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="billing-app-container"]/iframe')))
browser.switch_to.frame(iframe)
```

Comment: You should except your own answer... you can click the V under the # of votes

Answer (score 0):

Change your xpath:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 15)
the_input = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//input[@id="payment_amount_value"]')))
the_input.send_keys("Bla-bla")
```

Hope this helps you!